# Can Firefox script steal my files?

Tags: firefox, security, script

I use Xubuntu 18.04 and the way I use Firefox is this: I downloaded and unpacked Firefox in my home directory; then I "chmod a-w firefox" so that nothing in that directory can be modified.

Yesterday while I was searching, I accidentally clicked a link because my mouse bumped into a book, and the link led me to a strange advertisement site. There were some pop-ups which I closed. After a while, I hear that my backup external USB drive started spinning up, and after I logged out yesterday and logged back in today, I found that my desktop icon were re-arranged.

My question is: in Firefox Quantum 63.0.1, by just visiting a site, can the site automatically scan my computer and steal my files?

Thanks.

Comment: It can be startling when unexpected stuff happens on your computer.  But there are a lot of benign things that can result in your drive spinning up and the icons getting rearranged.  It's a big jump from there to the cause being malware, and random malware that does its dirty work in Linux at that.  Of course, you can't be absolutely certain that it wasn't; anything is possible.  But it's pretty improbable.

Answer (score 0):

It's not supposed to be possible on pure HTML without user interface like
dropping a file on an `<input>` tag or hitting an upload button.

However, I wouldn't say that it's not possible for a malicious website
to disguise its user interface so as to cause the user to hit such
a button without understanding the action behind.

For WebExtensions, they are supposed to be sandbagged without default access
to the file-system, that is without some user action to trigger that action.
You can read the draft for WebExtensions file-system interface in the article
[WebExtensions/Filesystem](https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebExtensions/Filesystem).

The browser may display the disk with a URL like this : `file://///`.
However, the `file:` protocol has no domain, so all sorts of things
can't work with such URLs, like `XMLHttpRequest`, `document.domain`, etc.,
so these URLs are not vulnerable because of the enforced "same domain" policy.

I would say that Firefox is reasonably protected against such upload/steal,
but cannot say with absolute conviction that no security exploits exist
in this area. Nobody really can.